# Create XElement from List<T> where T.property is null

Tags: c#, linq

I am receiving data from a Web Service.  The XML coming in is something like:

```
<data>
    <item>
        <code>a</code>
        <price>2.89</price>
    </item>
    <item>
        <code>a</code>
        <price>2.89</price>
        <colour>blue</colour>
    </item>
</data>
```

So, we see that one item has an additional property of Colour.

Okay, this gets converted into a List<item> which is the point at which I get hold of it.

I need to convert this list into an XDocument.

Using:

```
var xml = new XDocument(
new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-16", "yes"),
new XElement("data",
from i in myList
select new XElement("item",
new XElement("price", i.price),
new XElement("code", i.code),
new XElement("colour", i.colour))));
```

(I've typed this from memory, so excuse spellings)

Here, it errors because i.colour is null.

How do I cope with this?

Thanks in advance

Griff

Comment: What do you *want* to happen in the case when `colour` is `null` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to check whether i.colour is `null` before trying to access it.

You can do this neatly using the null-coalescing operator like:

```
new XElement("colour", i.colour ?? ""))));
```

Assuming that you want an empty string as the value if `i.colour` is `null`.

**UPDATE**

Based on your comment below, if you don't want the element added if `i.colour` is null then create it independantly of the `XDocument` instantiation and add it as required.

```
var xml = new XDocument(...);

if(i.colour != null)
{
  xml.Add(new XElement(...));
}
```

}

Comment: Unforutnately, if the property colour is null then I don't want the XElement created.

Comment: Unforunately your Update doesn't fit in with the `from ... select` syntax very well.

Comment: It's just an example of one way to acheive this result. Other methods are of course available to him.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid adding a new `XElement` when `colour` is null you can use the [ternary operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) and return null or the new `XElement` as appropriate:

```
var xml = new XDocument(
    new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-16", "yes"),
    new XElement("data",
    from i in myList
    select new XElement("item",
        new XElement("price", i.price),
        new XElement("code", i.code),
        i.colour == null ?
            null : new XElement("colour", i.colour)
    )));
```

Comment: And what does the ctor of XElement do with that?

Comment: OK, I checked: the null is ignored, no tag generated. What the OP asked for.